# Why isn't Swift's .sort( ) method able to guarantee stability if it's underlying algorithm are generally stable?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift's .sort( ) method does not guarantee stability. This is interesting because .sort( ) is based off Timsort, which comprises of merge  sort, insertion sort, & some other logic.

As far as I know - merge sort's normal implementation is stable, it has an in-place implementation which is also stable, & insertion sort is stable as well.

Why doesn't .sort( )  guarantee stability?

I've read the details in the following link, but I'm still unable to gather a good understanding of why it isn't stable. Someone commented that it is stable at the moment, and they aren't guaranteeing it to be stable because the implementation is subject to change in a future version of Swift & could become unstable at that point, but the other comments below that one are more difficult to comprehend.
https://forums.swift.org/t/is-sort-stable-in-swift-5/21297/9

And the Swift implementation of the method is available below for reference:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift

[image]

[image]

Comment: This has been discussed in the Swift forum: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-sort-stable-in-swift-5/21297.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, they are still deciding whether the algorithm should be stable or not by default, or whether there should be two functions (stable and unstable).

So they did a simple thing - they made it stable before Swift 5.0 but without guaranteeing it to be stable. Whatever they decide, they can make it backward compatible (if they decide the sort won't be stable, it doesn't matter if it has been stable before. If they decide the sort will be stable, then only documentation change is required).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there was a new unstable sort algorithm found, that real-world benchmarks/profiling shows to have better performance over the kind of data sets Swift programs most often work with.

By not guaranteeing stability, the standard library is free to change its sort implementation to use this new algorithm.

This ties in with [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/):

> With a sufficient number of users of an API, it does not matter what you promise in the contract:
>   all observable behaviors of your system will be depended on by somebody.

Undoubtedly, there's a lot of Swift code in the wild that depends on the stability of the standard library's sort. For example, someone might mistakenly write something like `people.sorted { $0.age < $1.age }.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }` to sort a collection of people first by their age, then breaking ties by their names. Such code currently works, but is technically invalid. If the standard library were to change to an unstable algorithm, all code like this would break. The library authors would then be in a position to say "I told you so", in that the stability wasn't a guaranteed quality of the algorithm.