# Swift - Sorting an array of structures by several members, how to do I do it better?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, struct

At the moment I am doing this :

```
arrayOfStruct.sort { $0.name < $1.name }

arrayOfStruct.sort { $0.subregion < $1.subregion }

arrayOfStruct.sort { $0.region < $1.region }
```

it works fine to sort names within subregions within regions
but the questions is how can I do it smarter?

Comment: Note that this works because sort() happens to be a stable sort – a fact on which you should not rely because it is not documented.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/61191854/1187415

Answer (score 2):

If your sort has up to six members you can simply use a single sort passing a tuple:

```
arrayOfStruct.sort { ($0.region, $0.subregion, $0.name) < ($1.region, $1.subregion, $1.name) }
```